# Variable DC Supply "Ignoring" Potentiometer

Tags: power-supply, dc, potentiometer

I printed a board meant to supply a variable 5–250VDC from this open-source schematic:

[image: source schematic]

This was my board

[image: board in EAGLE]

with this schematic (excuse my silly device symbols)

[image: shematic in EAGLE]

but I can't get the output voltage to vary. With the 5k potentiometer (the box at the bottom center of the board), it measured ~320V, invariant of the pot's setting. For a 10k pot, it measured the same voltage, again invariant.

Here's the soldered print (excuse the poor quality, someone else has them currently):

[image: top soldered]
[image: bottom soldered]

Is something shorting? Is it somehow "skipping" the potentiometer? Is there anything obviously incorrect or any likely errors I could test for?

Comment: Looks this board routing was designed by Picasso...

Comment: @EugeneSh. haha I have no experience with routing, and EAGLE's autorouter didn't do too much (probably because my component placement wasn't very wise)

Comment: The routing on your PCB looks like an abstract art project ...

Comment: @brhans as you can probably guess, it was done very quickly haha

Comment: Without knowing what is to the right of your schematic it is difficult to understand your circuit. You have connected POT1 as a variable resistor rather than a potential divider. When you turn it to zero it will short that line to GND. Is that what you intended?

Comment: At what load? You may be in deep discontinuous mode and your PWM circuit might have limited minimum duty cycle.

Comment: @Transistor to the right are connectors to take the high voltage supply and  ground to another board (and the other board does what it's supposed to with the supply voltage). And I guess that's not what I intended. I took this circuit from an existing open-source project, so I'm not entirely familiar with it; however, it seems to work fine for them. How would you recommend changing it?

Comment: How about a link to that open source design?

Comment: @winny it exhibits this behavior both when we just read the supply from its output pins using a multimeter, and when we connect it to the other board (whose load I'm not entirely sure about—I'm having someone check)

Comment: @Andyaka sure! I'll add it to the question body

Comment: The capacitors on the HV side are all underrated if you are expecting 300+ Volts.  You have a 200 Volt electrolytic, and a 250 Volt ceramic.  Neither of those should be anywhere near that 300V output.

Comment: @JRE That's a good point. I wasn't expecting 320V, but it's definitely there…

Comment: @JRE another good point. I'm curious to see where I diverged from the original schematic…

Comment: @JRE LOL! That might be what's actually limiting the output from fetting any higher.

Comment: Even if it were working correctly, C4 and C6 are underrated.  There's a note in the original schematic that says the output varies from 65 to 260VDC - which exceeds the ratings that are also right next to the parts.

Comment: @JRE interesting. I'm thinking I should just suck it up and design my own supply…

Comment: Looking over the original.  They are using the same voltage divider arrangement around Pot1.

Comment: And for the love of God, take another picture - you know, one that is sharp.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast can't, currently. Boards are with someone whose only camera is dependably blurry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this PCB is unlikely to ever work. You will need to redesign it.

Switching power supply designs are very sensitive to layout. In particular, it's critical to minimize the area and inductance of the current loop. Unfortunately, your design places the inductor rather arbitrarily, which leaves the current loop all over the place. For more information on these aspects of design, you may want to read some application notes on switching PSU design, such as:

- [Linear Technology: PCB Layout Considerations for Non-Isolated Switching Power Supplies](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an136f.pdf)
- [TI: Five Steps to a Good PCB Layout of a Boost Converter](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva773/slva773.pdf)

I also see a couple of generic issues with your PCB design, including:

- Your layout is not making use of its ground pour. A good ground is critical for all circuits, but is particularly important for a power supply design.
- One of the terminals of C1 appears to be unrouted.
- As other users have mentioned, it looks like you may have chosen some parts which are not rated for the voltages you're trying to produce.
- You are using rather arbitrary packages and footprints for a lot of parts. For instance, you're using a Kelvin resistor footprint for RSENSE1, but ignoring the kelvin terminals, and it almost looks like you've soldered an electrolytic capacitor to a SMD capacitor footprint on the back side. Switching power supplies are sensitive to lead inductance; these choices matter!

Comment: Ah, layout. I've read that layout was critical to HV supplies but had no idea why. Though the ground pours didn't render, C1's other terminal is actually routed to the ground pour on that side of the board. But it makes sense that our other layout decisions would screw up the functionality. I will certainly read what you linked and be much more assiduous when re-designing. Thanks!

Comment: It's not specific to HV power supplies. Layout is critical to _all_ high-frequency analog designs -- which includes switching power supplies, regardless of their output voltage.

Comment: I'll definitely keep that in mind for the future. The PDFs you linked were super informative, too—thanks!